# Pandas - Find Max Count of 2 Dependent Attribute and Replace Duplicate Rows with that Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working in pandas and I have a dataset/dataframe which looks like this.

```
venueId                     venueCategoryId             venueCategory
v1                          vc1                         Airport
v1                          vc2                         Park     
v1                          vc1                         Airport
v2                          vc3                         American Restaurant
v3                          vc4                         Italian Restaurant
v3                          vc5                         Restaurant
```

venueId represents unique venues and category represents what type of venue that is. CategoryId and CategoryName values are related.

I am trying to replace the venueCategoryId and venueCategory of a venue with the Category which was highest in that venue.

The Result I am trying to get:

```
venueId                     venueCategoryId             venueCategory
v1                          vc1                         Airport
v2                          vc3                         American Restaurant
v3                          vc4                         Italian Restaurant
```

I was trying to use groupby on 'venueId' column to group and find the count and replace with highest count. But I couldn't figure out how to venueCategoryId and venueCategory as a dependent column in pandas and find max of  2 column and replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution via [`pd.Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html). There is likely a more Pandorable method.

```
# combine id and category series
df['venueIdCat'] = list(zip(df.venueCategoryId, df.venueCategory))

# groupby venueId and extract mode
res = df.groupby('venueId')['venueIdCat'].apply(pd.Series.mode).reset_index()

# unsplit id and category
res = res.join(pd.DataFrame(res['venueIdCat'].values.tolist(),
                            columns=['venueCategoryId', 'venueCategory']))

# select required columns
res = res[['venueId', 'venueCategoryId', 'venueCategory']]

print(res)

  venueId venueCategoryId       venueCategory
0      v1             vc1             Airport
1      v2             vc3  AmericanRestaurant
2      v3             vc4   ItalianRestaurant
```

---

Alternative solution using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

# combine id and category series
df['venueIdCat'] = list(zip(df.venueCategoryId, df.venueCategory))

# groupby venueId and extract mode
res = df.groupby('venueId')['venueIdCat'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common()[0][0]).reset_index()

# unsplit id and category
res = res.join(pd.DataFrame(res['venueIdCat'].values.tolist(),
                            columns=['venueCategoryId', 'venueCategory']))

# select required columns
res = res[['venueId', 'venueCategoryId', 'venueCategory']]

print(res)

  venueId venueCategoryId       venueCategory
0      v1             vc1             Airport
1      v2             vc3  AmericanRestaurant
2      v3             vc4   ItalianRestaurant
```

Comment: It does most of the work. Only issue that remained was that when  venueCategoryId number are same like (e.g: v1 instead of having vc1 twice it have it only once) . Then it keeps both vc1 and vc2 , I wanted to keep either one doesnt matter which.

Comment: @KevinStephenBiswas, Sorry, I don't understand. Maybe you can give an example demonstrating where desired output is different to the method I've outlined?

Comment: @KevinStephenBiswas, [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50934941/edit), please, with new input & desired output - I can't read code in comments.

Comment: In v3 there is no max both category occurs one time. When used mode it keeps both row of v3 but I wanted either one.